Interpreting the implication arrow as the copula "is" or "are"
Rather than interpreting the implication arrow as referring to the material conditional, can you interpret the implication arrow as referring to the copula “is” or “are”? I ask because from a natural language perspective, it seems more natural to do it this way. To give you an example of what I mean, let the following hold. Let the implication arrow signify the copula “is” or “are”. Let D signify all dogs. Let C signify all cats. Let M signify mammals. So, we have (C→M)∧(D→M)|=(C∧D→M), which translates to all cats are mammals and all dogs are mammals implies all cats and all dogs are mammals. Now, if we were to negate (C∧D→M), it would be (C∧D→¬M) or all cats and all dogs aren’t mammals. Also note, the copula “is” or “are” can be interpreted as a morphism.

The usual translation of "Every Cat is a Mammal" is ∀x (Cx → Mx).

@MauroALLEGRANZA, but why do we have to adhere to that translation though? It doesn’t follow natural language.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, or why do we have to use first order logic to represent that statement?

We don’t. “Every cat is a mammal” is an exactly equivalent statement. But in FOL (i.e. the notation you suggest we change), the exact translation would be (for every thing)(it being a cat implies it is a mammal). I don’t think there’s a way to break it down further. FOL is, importantly, completely distinct from natural language.

@controlgroup, by translation I mean translation into FOL

That is simply how the translation goes. There is no reason it needs to correspond directly to anything in natural language.

The negation of (A->B) is not (A->~B), unless you’re using a sort of connexive implication.

Yes. I am using some form of connexive implication since the implication arrow signifies the copula is or are.

A conditional connective cannot do justice to all the ways the copula ('is' in English) is used. Many logicians distinguish:

The 'is' of predication (John is tall)
The 'is' of identity (George Orwell is Eric Blair)

and some also further distinguish

The 'is' of existence (There is a king of Norway)

The 'is' of subsumption (The whale is a mammal)


In formal logic we usually handle these in the following way:

We say that a predicate is satisfied by an individual. The individual John satisfies the predicate "___ is tall". Usually written Tall(john) or maybe just Tj. This can be extended to multi-place predicates.

We use the identity predicate. george_orwell = eric_blair. This can be regarded as a notational shorthand for Identical(george_orwell, eric_blair).

We use the existential quantifier. (∃x)King_of_Norway(x).

This can be written in different ways depending on exactly what we are trying to express. We could write (∀x)(Whale(x) ⊃ Mammal(x)) with a material conditional ⊃ and this would express that any thing that is a whale is also a mammal. We could also use set theory and say that the set Whale is a subset of the set Mammal.


The drawback of both of these options is that they are purely extensional. They do not do justice to the fact that whales are a kind of mammal and hence if a thing is a whale it must be a mammal. This is quite unlike an accidental generalisation such as: "All the pencils in my pocket are yellow". We might express it instead as a subtype relation in a typed language.
We might also use a connexive conditional, as you suggest in your comment. (Ax)(Whale(x) → Mammal(x)) where A is a connexive universal quantifier and → is a connexive conditional. This has the consequence that the negation of (Ax)(Whale(x) → Mammal(x)) is (Ax)(Whale(x) → ¬Mammal(x)). This makes the denial of "The whale is a mammal" to be "The whale is not a mammal". Weird, but maybe not entirely implausible when speaking of universals.
Another option would be to use a modal operator □(∀x)(Whale(x) ⊃ Mammal(x)) to indicate that this sentence has a special modal status and is not merely extensional.
